# Decoding Custom BLE Service Data for Heart Rate and Step Count etc. in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a Flutter project involving a Bluetooth Low Energy device (Xiaomi Smart Watch) , and I'm using the flutter_blue package. My objective is to retrieve health-related data, specifically heart rate and step count, from this device. However, it does not adhere to the standard Bluetooth GATT profiles and instead uses custom services and characteristics.I have successfully connected to the device and accessed one of these custom services. From one of the characteristics, I am receiving the following byte array:

```
[8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 125, 99, 193, 62, 88, 43, 0, 81, 120, 75, 37, 76]
```

I am struggling to interpret this data. My goal is to identify and extract meaningful information like heart rate and step count from this or similar byte arrays provided by the device's custom services.
So far, I have attempted the following without much success:

- ASCII Conversion
- Base64 Encoding

I am looking for guidance or suggestions on how to decode and understand this data. Are there common patterns or structures in BLE communications for such health-related data, even in custom services? How can I approach this problem to extract meaningful health data such as heart rate and step count?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there aren't any common patterns or structures which you can use to decode the data, and at the end of the day it is completely up to the manufacturer how they format their data in their custom BLE services/characteristics. If you want to decode this data, your best bet is to contact Xiaomi and ask them about this. If this doesn't yield anything, then you have to reverse engineer this yourself. I would start with trying to match what the watch is displaying to the data that you are reading via BLE. For example, if your step number is 100, look for the value 100 (0x64 in hex) in the BLE data. Then take one extra step to get the step number to 101, and then look for 0x65 in the data, and so on. You will need to do something similar with the heart rate where you have to constantly match the reading on the watch to the data that you are receiving. Of course this is all assuming that the data is sent in plaintext and it is not encrypted.

There have been attempts to read Xiaomi data in the best, so maybe these links below are helpful:-

- [BLE reverse engineering Mi Band 5](https://medium.com/@_celianvdb/ble-reverse-engineering-mi-band-5-c3deed12c7)
- [I hacked Mi Band 3 and here's how I did it](https://medium.com/@yogeshojha/i-hacked-xiaomi-miband-3-and-here-is-how-i-did-it-43d68c272391)
- [Reverse engineering the M6 smart bracelet](https://rbaron.net/blog/2021/07/06/Reverse-engineering-the-M6-smart-fitness-band.html)